# Compare two GPX-files of same route

Tags: webapp-rec

Does a web-app like this exist:

I have several recordings of gps-coordinates (gpx or tcx-format) from biking the same route several times. It would be awesome to compare two (or more) of them at the same time visually, similar to ghost-mode i some driving computer games.

I have searched but not found anything that can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [SportTracks](http://www.zonefivesoftware.com/SportTracks/).

> - GPS import or manual workout entry

Answer (score -1):

Please find a link below to a Beta program (Windows 7 only supported at the moment) which allows for the import of two TCX files (sorry, GPX files not supported at the moment). It was the ghost mode I experienced within some driving games that was the inspiration for this program:

http://www.gpsrunner.co.uk/Videos.html

If biking mode is detected, the 'runners' are replaced with basic bicycles. Also, there is a mode whereby life force is assigned to each of the data imported. If enabled, the life force depletes if either:

1. A heart rate threshold is exceeded
   [image: 3D View of similar tcx imported data]
2. A minimum speed is not maintained

Comment: You need to disclose your affiliations.

Comment: I think the disclosure is implied, honestly.  I think this post is so old that it's not really of any consequence at this point.